# Filtrar array de objetos a partir de uma string de busca em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho um array de objetos em que, certas vezes, uma propriedade pode vir `null`.

Preciso aplicar um filtro nesse array para capturar os objetos que possuam o campo e funcionalidade que são passados por uma `string` em uma diretiva no meu front-end.

A string é passada da seguinte forma: `campo#funcionalidade`, porém se o campo for `null`, a string será `#funcionalidade`.

Não estou conseguindo fazer o filtro de forma correta para que o objeto seja retornado quando o campo for nulo ou a string campo der *match*.

Segue exemplo do código:

```js
const funcionalidades = [
  {
    "campo": null,
    "funcionalidadeNome":"configuracoes.cadastrocliente",
    "descricao":"Aqui é preenchido os dados básicos do cliente"
  },
  {
    "campo":"cnpj",
    "funcionalidadeNome":"configuracoes.cadastrocliente",
    "descricao":"CNPJ do cliente"
  },
  {
    "campo":"codigo",
    "funcionalidadeNome":"configuracoes.cadastrocliente",
    "descricao":"Código do cliente"
  },
  {
    "campo":"nome",
    "funcionalidadeNome":"configuracoes.cadastrocliente",
    "descricao":"Nome Fanstasia"
  },
  {
    "campo":"razaosocial",
    "funcionalidadeNome":"configuracoes.cadastrocliente",
    "descricao":"Razão Social"
  }
];

const aaa = (arr, teste) => {
  const [ campo, funcionalidade] = teste.split('#')
  console.log(`CAMPO: ${campo}, FUNCIONALIDADE: ${funcionalidade}`)
  
  return arr
    .filter(item => item.funcionalidadeNome === funcionalidade)
    .find(item => item.campo === campo)
}

console.log(aaa(funcionalidades, 'codigo#configuracoes.cadastrocliente'));
console.log(aaa(funcionalidades, 'cnpj#configuracoes.cadastrocliente'));
console.log(aaa(funcionalidades, '#configuracoes.cadastrocliente'));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtn0m94c/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note que, quando a string está em um padrão como `foo#bar` e você a divide pelo caractere `#`, retorna-se um array como:

```
['foo', 'bar']
```

Mas, quando a string encontra-se num padrão como `#bar` e você a divide pelo caractere `#`, retorna-se um array como:

```
['', 'bar']
```

Então assume-se que, quando o primeiro elemento do array for uma string vazia, a propriedade `campo` do objeto a ser filtrado deve ser `null`.

Aplicando isso na lógica de filtragem, tem-se algo assim:

```js
function filtrarArray(arr, stringDeFiltragem) {
  let [campo, funcionalidade] = stringDeFiltragem.split('#');
  if (campo === '') {
    campo = null;
  }

  return arr
    .filter((item) => item.funcionalidadeNome === funcionalidade)
    .find((item) => item.campo === campo);
}

const funcionalidades = [
  {
    campo: null,
    funcionalidadeNome: 'configuracoes.cadastrocliente',
    descricao: 'Aqui é preenchido os dados básicos do cliente'
  },
  {
    campo: 'cnpj',
    funcionalidadeNome: 'configuracoes.cadastrocliente',
    descricao: 'CNPJ do cliente'
  },
  {
    campo: 'codigo',
    funcionalidadeNome: 'configuracoes.cadastrocliente',
    descricao: 'Código do cliente'
  },
  {
    campo: 'nome',
    funcionalidadeNome: 'configuracoes.cadastrocliente',
    descricao: 'Nome Fanstasia'
  },
  {
    campo: 'razaosocial',
    funcionalidadeNome: 'configuracoes.cadastrocliente',
    descricao: 'Razão Social'
  }
];

console.log(filtrarArray(funcionalidades, 'codigo#configuracoes.cadastrocliente'));
console.log(filtrarArray(funcionalidades, 'cnpj#configuracoes.cadastrocliente'));
console.log(filtrarArray(funcionalidades, '#configuracoes.cadastrocliente'));
```

Mas note que o uso do `filter` não chega a ser necessário nesse caso, uma vez que pode-se fazer toda a "lógica de seleção" direto no `find`. Veja:

```
function filtrarArray(arr, stringDeFiltragem) {
  let [campo, funcionalidade] = stringDeFiltragem.split('#');
  if (campo === '') {
    campo = null;
  }

  return arr.find((item) =>
    item.funcionalidadeNome === funcionalidade &&
    item.campo === campo
  );
}
```

Nesse caso, basta utilizar o operador lógico AND (`&&`) para executar as duas condições ao mesmo tempo no predicado passado ao `Array.prototype.find`. O resultado é exatamente o mesmo, mas a vantagem é que não precisa varrer o array duas vezes.

---

E claro, se o `if` estiver "verboso demais", seja *cool*  e utilize o [operador de atribuição lógica `||=`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/485889/69296), introduzido em uma edição recente do ECMAScript. Ficaria assim:

```
function filtrarArray(arr, stringDeFiltragem) {
  let [campo, funcionalidade] = stringDeFiltragem.split('#');
  campo ||= null;

  return arr.find((item) =>
    item.funcionalidadeNome === funcionalidade &&
    item.campo === campo
  );
}
```

Comment: Sim! :) Mas preferi utilizar o `if` para ser menos "complicado". Algumas pessoas podem não saber como esse operador funciona. De todo modo, @CmteCardeal, deixe seu comentário para mostrar essa possibilidade para futuros leitores, obrigado!

Comment: Ah, @CmteCardeal, mais legal ainda seria usar o [`||=`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/485878/69296), hehe! :D

Comment: @CmteCardeal realmente pode confundir usar esse operador por isso usei operador ternário na minha resposta, mas esta resposta ainda melhorou o código, muito bom

Comment: @CmteCardeal Lembrando que nem sempre o uso do `||` dará o mesmo resultado do `if`:  https://ideone.com/kL0eKN (no caso da pergunta, acho que sim, porque o `split` retorna um array de strings, mas dependendo do caso, pode ser que dê diferença)

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa considerar no `find()` que o valor de campo pode ser `undefined`, pois no `split()` o primeiro índice da array fica `undefined` para o campo segue exemplo com seu código modificado:

```js
const funcionalidades = [
    {
    "campo": null,
    "funcionalidadeNome":"configuracoes.cadastrocliente",
    "descricao":"Aqui é preenchido os dados básicos do cliente"
  },
  {
    "campo":"cnpj",
    "funcionalidadeNome":"configuracoes.cadastrocliente",
    "descricao":"CNPJ do cliente"
  },
  {
    "campo":"codigo",
    "funcionalidadeNome":"configuracoes.cadastrocliente",
    "descricao":"Código do cliente"
  },
  {
    "campo":"nome",
    "funcionalidadeNome":"configuracoes.cadastrocliente",
    "descricao":"Nome Fanstasia"
  },
  {
    "campo":"razaosocial",
    "funcionalidadeNome":"configuracoes.cadastrocliente",
    "descricao":"Razão Social"
  }
];

const aaa = (arr, teste) => {
    const [ campo, funcionalidade] = teste.split('#');
  console.log(`CAMPO: ${campo}, FUNCIONALIDADE: ${funcionalidade}`)
  
    return arr
    .filter(item => item.funcionalidadeNome === funcionalidade)
    .find(item => item.campo === (!campo ? null : campo))
}

console.log(aaa(funcionalidades, 'codigo#configuracoes.cadastrocliente'));
console.log(aaa(funcionalidades, 'cnpj#configuracoes.cadastrocliente'));
console.log(aaa(funcionalidades, '#configuracoes.cadastrocliente'));
```

Comment: `undefined` é diferente de `null` em javascript